# Count array values (x), then repeat script (x) times, each time using next value in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I would like to take the first value in an array and use it within a function. Then, I would like to repeat the function using the second value in the array. This should make use of count(); so that it stops once it reaches the end of the array. This seems simple enough, but I have no idea how to move to the next array value without writing a separate function. Quick Googling yielded something about `for`, but I'm not sure what to make of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most basic PHP tutorials would have shown you this language construct. But, for the sake of being friendly, PHP includes multiple ways to iterate over an array and perform an action. Consider the following:

```
function writeArrayItem($item) {
    echo $item . '<br>';
}

$array = [1, 2, 3];

foreach ($array as $item) {
    writeArrayItem($item);
}
```

We create a simple little function that takes a value and ECHO's it back out. Then we instantiate an array object with three values, 1, 2 and 3.

After this, we use PHP's FOREACH iterator to loop over each value in the array, casting that value into the variable $item. Within the loop, we call the function we previously declared, and hand it the value we want it to echo out.

There are other loop constructs you could use, but FOREACH is a very helpful tool when you want to iterate over each value in an array.

If you must (for school purposes) make use of count(), then a FOR loop would be your choice. Use the same function above, and change the foreach to this FOR code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    writeArrayItem($array[$i]);
}
```

The change here is we have to manually track the index in the array and use it to retrieve the value. We also use the number of items in the array to predicate how many loop cycles we will have. Because arrays are zero-based indexes, your starting value is usually 0, and you want to loop to the number of items in the array minus 1.

In this case we use:

```
$i < count($array)
```

Once $i reaches 2, the loop will stop because we are saying to loop while $i is smaller than count($array) which equals 3, and because on a zero-based index, array[2] is actually the third index as the first index is array[0];

Hope all that helps!